# PHP/Zend: Overhead of large number of unused variables and functions

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a PHP-file that is included by a lot of other PHP-scripts, which all use only a subset of the functions and variables defined in that included file. (I guess this is the usual case for most larger libaries.)

For this reason, in most cases only a small part of the included file is actually used and most of it simply ignored (unused functions, never referenced variables, etc.).

But AFAIK all recent versions of PHP come with the Zend-optimizer, which as far as I understand it, produces some kind of bytecode that is then used at runtime. It therefore should filter out all unused code, so even a huge number of unused functions would cause zero overhead at runtime.

Is this the case or is there a performance overhead for using large libraries in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP 5.5 change log of new features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.opcache):

> The Zend Optimiser+ opcode cache has been added to PHP as the new
>   OPcache extension. OPcache improves PHP performance by storing
>   precompiled script bytecode in shared memory, thereby removing the
>   need for PHP to load and parse scripts on each request.

What I understand from that statement is that every .php file, when converted into bytecode, will be saved into `shared memory` so that the conversion does not need be repeated per file. As we are no longer performing that step our processing time goes down.

This means that the uncalled functions and un-needed variables get declared and stored in the cache but never used.

> is there a performance overhead for using large libraries in PHP?

The answer to that is almost always "yes". There have been numerous benchmarks that say that a library is slow, even when using OPCaching (such as APC or Zend Optimiser).

Comment: Is OPCaching part of the standard PHP distribution and is it enabled by default?